# How to change layout of dialog preference in Android live wallpaper?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, live-wallpaper

I am trying to have a custom dialog preference that when inflated each selection invokes an Intent and that the inflated dialog has a custom layout. I am also trying to show a custom xml layout on the preference itself. Meaning where it first shows on the settings screen prior to being selected. I have a custom xml layout that would show text to the left and 4 icon images to the right. I want each icon to be selectable from there or in the dialog popup. Each with its on intent. I know this is possible because I've seen it within a live wallpaper. I understand how to call an Intent and apply a custom layout, but with what I've tried I get the error "unable to inflate dialog". Any help would be greatly appreciated. You can view my code here: [TestLWP Settings](https://github.com/power7714/TestLWP)

Here is an image of what I am trying to achieve:[image: Preview1]

[image]

Comment: I think you use one `list` for showing your info but the first image just have 4 image that put side by side each other and two or three `textview`, did I say right about your implement?

Comment: Please post some code with what you have tried and ask specific question to get specific answer. Is your problem implementing a custom preference layout? Is your problem implementing a custom dialog layout? Is your problem opening a dialog on preference click?

Comment: All of my code is in the github link provided. I tried adding the custom dialog preference to my settings xml. The live wallpaper loaded but when i clicked on settings, it crashed and the logcat said" failed to inflate dialog. That is where i am stuck because it's not supposed to inflate until that specific setting is selected. My custom seekbar preference didn't do that. The xml layouts for both the setting screen and the dialog look like they're supposed to. I just need the setting screen to show the way it's supposed to and then i can figure out the rest.

Comment: Solved my problem. For anyone that wants to use this dialogpreference for their own app/live wallpaper the code is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out how to achieve the above two images. I am including the code here for anyone who wants to use it. I have also commented the code in detail to explain what is happening.

First create a class that extends DialogPreference and add the folloing:

```
        import android.app.Dialog;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.preference.DialogPreference;
        import android.util.AttributeSet;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;

        public class SocialPref extends DialogPreference implements OnClickListener
        {




          public SocialPref(Context paramContext, AttributeSet paramChar)
          {
            super(paramContext, paramChar);
            //Use setWidgetLayoutResource to display the setting how you
            //want it in the settings screen
            setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.pref_social);
            //Set the title of the setting
            setTitle(R.string.SocialTitle);
            //Set the summary for the setting
            setSummary(R.string.SocialSummary);
            //Here you set the title for the Dialog
            setDialogTitle(R.string.SocialTitle);
            //Here you declare the layout for the Dialog
            setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.pref_social_dialog);
            setNegativeButtonText(R.string.Cancel);
          }



          //Void a,b,c,and d are called when each icon is pressed
          //on the setting or when each list item is selected within the dialog.
          //allowing the user to select each social site from the setting or the dialog.
          //each action includes an intent that launches the corresponding social site.
          private void a(View paramView, int paramInt)
          {
            if (paramView != null)
            {
              View localView = paramView.findViewById(paramInt);
              if (localView != null)
                localView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public final void onClick(View paramView)
                      {
                        this.gPlus();
                      }

                    private void gPlus()
                      {
                        Dialog localDialog = getDialog();
                        if (localDialog != null)
                          localDialog.dismiss();
                        Context localContext = getContext();
                        if (localContext != null)
                        {
                          Intent localIntent = new Intent();
                          localIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
                          //Important: put your G+ page where it says "gplus_account_here" or it won't work
                          localIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/gplus_account_here"));
                          localContext.startActivity(localIntent);
                        }
                      }
                });
            }
          }

          private void b(View paramView, int paramInt)
          {
            if (paramView != null)
            {
              View localView = paramView.findViewById(paramInt);
              if (localView != null)
                localView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        this.faceBook();

                    }
                    private void faceBook()
                      {
                        Dialog localDialog = getDialog();
                        if (localDialog != null)
                          localDialog.dismiss();
                        Context localContext = getContext();
                        if (localContext != null)
                        {
                          Intent localIntent1 = new Intent();
                          localIntent1.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
                          //Important: put your FaceBook id and page in their respective locations
                          //or it won't work.
                          localIntent1.setData(Uri.parse("fb://profile/profile_id"));
                          Intent localIntent2 = ac.a(localContext, localIntent1, false);
                          if (localIntent2 == null)
                          {
                            localIntent2 = new Intent();
                            localIntent2.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
                            localIntent2.setData(Uri.parse("https://facebook.com/profile_page"));
                          }
                          localContext.startActivity(localIntent2);
                        }
                      }



              });
          }
        }

          private void c(View paramView, int paramInt)
          {
            if (paramView != null)
            {
              View localView = paramView.findViewById(paramInt);
              if (localView != null)
                localView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        this.twitter();
                    }
                    private void twitter()
                      {
                        Dialog localDialog = getDialog();
                        if (localDialog != null)
                          localDialog.dismiss();
                        Context localContext = getContext();
                        if (localContext != null)
                        {
                          Intent localIntent1 = new Intent();
                          localIntent1.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
                          //Important: put your Twitter screen name where it says
                          //"screen_name_here" or it won't work
                          localIntent1.setData(Uri.parse("twitter://user?screen_name=screen_name_here"));
                          Intent localIntent2 = ac.a(localContext, localIntent1, false);
                          if (localIntent2 == null)
                          {
                            localIntent2 = new Intent();
                            localIntent2.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
                            localIntent2.setData(Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=screen_name_here"));
                          }
                          localContext.startActivity(localIntent2);
                        }
                      }
                });
            }
          }

          private void d(View paramView, int paramInt)
          {
            if (paramView != null)
            {
                View localView = paramView.findViewById(paramInt);
                if (localView != null)
                  localView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                  {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View paramView) {
                        this.youTube();
                    }
                    private void youTube()
                      {
                        Dialog localDialog = getDialog();
                        if (localDialog != null)
                          localDialog.dismiss();
                        Context localContext = getContext();
                        if (localContext != null)
                        {
                          Intent localIntent = new Intent();
                          localIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
                          //Important: Put your YouTube channel name where it 
                          //says "username_here" or it won't work
                          localIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/user/username_here"));
                          localContext.startActivity(localIntent);
                        }
                      }

                  });
            }
          }


        //This instantiates the view for the dialog
          //and allows each icon to be clickable
          protected final View onCreateDialogView()
          {
            View localView = super.onCreateDialogView();
            //For example: when a(localView, d.tv_social_gplus); is
            //called, public void a(); is started taking the user
            //to the related social site or app
            a(localView, d.tv_social_gplus);
            b(localView, d.tv_social_facebook);
            c(localView, d.tv_social_twitter);
            d(localView, d.tv_social_ytube);
            return localView;
          }

          //This instantiates the view for the setting within the setting
          //screen and allows each icon to be clicked, invoking
          //the corresponding action.
          protected final View onCreateView(ViewGroup paramViewGroup)
          {
            View localView = super.onCreateView(paramViewGroup);
            a(localView, d.iv_social_gplus);
            b(localView, d.iv_social_facebook);
            c(localView, d.iv_social_twitter);
            d(localView, d.iv_social_ytube);
            return localView;
          }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        }
```

Then create an empty class called "d" to store the integers:

```
                public final class d
        {


          public static final int iv_social_facebook = R.id.iv_social_facebook;
          public static final int iv_social_gplus = R.id.iv_social_gplus;
          public static final int iv_social_twitter = R.id.iv_social_twitter;
          public static final int iv_social_ytube = R.id.iv_social_ytube;

          public static final int tv_social_facebook = R.id.tv_social_facebook;
          public static final int tv_social_gplus = R.id.tv_social_gplus;
          public static final int tv_social_twitter = R.id.tv_social_twitter;
          public static final int tv_social_ytube = R.id.tv_social_ytube;

        }
```

This is the xml for the setting, name it "pref_social":

```
            <LinearLayout 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:id="@+id/iv_social_ytube" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/value_margin_half" 
            android:src="@drawable/selector_ytube" />
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:id="@+id/iv_social_gplus" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/value_margin_half" 
            android:src="@drawable/selector_gplus" />
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:id="@+id/iv_social_facebook" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/value_margin_half" 
            android:src="@drawable/selector_fb" />
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:id="@+id/iv_social_twitter" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/value_margin_half" 
            android:src="@drawable/selector_twitter" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

This xml is the layout for the Dialog, name it "pref_social_dialog.xml":

```
            <LinearLayout android:gravity="left" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="@dimen/value_margin_half"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <TextView android:gravity="left|center" android:id="@+id/tv_social_ytube" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="@dimen/value_margin_half" android:text="@string/Social_YouTube" android:drawableLeft="@drawable/selector_ytube" android:drawablePadding="@dimen/value_margin" />
        <View android:background="?android:listDivider" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1.0dip" />
        <TextView android:gravity="left|center" android:id="@+id/tv_social_gplus" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="@dimen/value_margin_half" android:text="@string/Social_GooglePlus" android:drawableLeft="@drawable/selector_gplus" android:drawablePadding="@dimen/value_margin" />
        <View android:background="?android:listDivider" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1.0dip" />
        <TextView android:gravity="left|center" android:id="@+id/tv_social_facebook" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="@dimen/value_margin_half" android:text="@string/Social_Facebook" android:drawableLeft="@drawable/selector_fb" android:drawablePadding="@dimen/value_margin" />
        <View android:background="?android:listDivider" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1.0dip" />
        <TextView android:gravity="left|center" android:id="@+id/tv_social_twitter" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="@dimen/value_margin_half" android:text="@string/Social_Twitter" android:drawableLeft="@drawable/selector_twitter" android:drawablePadding="@dimen/value_margin" />
        <View android:background="?android:listDivider" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1.0dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Create an xml file for the icons in the drawable folder. This will change the icon when selected. Call it " selector_fb.xml"  Create the same for YouTube, Twitter, and GPlus like this: "selector_ytube.xml", "selector_twitter.xml", "selector_gplus.xml"

```
            <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/fb" />
        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/fb_pressed" />

    </selector>
```

You'll have to use your own images. Just make sure the selected one is grayscale and that all images are sized correctly for each size of device. Hope this helps someone else.